# Numpy speed efficiency using broadcasting, transpose and reshape in large size array

Tags: numpy, performance, reshape, array-broadcasting

Is there a way to speed up the following line of code:

```
desired_channel=32
len_indices=50000
fast_idx = np.broadcast_to(np.arange(desired_channel)[:, None], (desired_channel, len_indices)).T.reshape(-1)
```

Thank you.

Comment: so what are you suggesting?

Comment: *Numba* should help to speed up a lot the code using plain loops although the resulting code will be quite low-level.

Answer (score 1):

The last line of code is simply equal to `np.tile(np.arange(desired_channel), len_indices)`.

On my machine, the performance of `np.tile` like many Numpy calls is bounded by the operating system (*page faults*), the memory allocator and the memory throughput. There are two ways to overcome this limitation: **not to allocate/fill temporary buffers**, to produce **smaller arrays** in memory using *shorter types* like `np.uint8` or `np.uint16` regarding your needs.

Since there is no `out` parameter for the `np.tile` function, Numba can be used to generate a fast alternative function. Here is an example:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('int32[::1](int32, int32, int32[::1])', parallel=True)
def generate(desired_channel, len_indices, out):
    for i in nb.prange(len_indices):
        for j in range(desired_channel):
            out[i*desired_channel+j] = j
    return out

desired_channel=32
len_indices=50000
buffer = np.full(desired_channel * len_indices, 0, dtype=np.int32)
%timeit -n 200 generate(desired_channel, len_indices, fast_idx)
```

Here are the performance results:

```
Original code: 1.25 ms
np.tile:       1.24 ms
Numba:         0.20 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to **jax** library. I have compared your code by jax one using the following code on *Colab TPU*:

```
import numpy as np
from jax import jit
import jax.numpy as jnp
import timeit

desired_channel=32
len_indices=50000

def ex_():
    return np.broadcast_to(np.arange(desired_channel)[:, None], (desired_channel, len_indices)).T.reshape(-1)
%timeit -n1000 -r10 ex_()

@jit
def exj_():
    return jnp.broadcast_to(jnp.arange(desired_channel)[:, None], (desired_channel, len_indices)).T.reshape(-1)
%timeit -n1000 -r10 exj_()
```

in one of my efforts, the results were as:

> 1000 loops, best of 10: 901 µs per loop
> 1000 loops, best of 10: 317 µs per loop

in this way, **jax** could speed up your code about two to three times.